# Cannot get back to parent view when navigating to child view from another tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have an application that uses Ionic tabs; a simple example of my problem can be reproduced [there](http://codepen.io/piwinux/pen/BNYXKd).

There are two tabs: `home` and `settings`.

In the state manager, there is a single top-level (abstract) state `tabs`. The nested `tabs.home` state describes the `home` tab. The nested `tabs.settings` state is abstract and contains two nested states: `tabs.settings.index` and `tabs.settings.sub`. The former describes the `settings` tab, and the latter shows a sub-view of my `settings` tab (a very simple example of this setup can be found on the [UI router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples)).

The `home` tab offers a button to navigate to the `tabs.settings.sub` state directly (it uses `$state.go()`, but the behavior is the same when using `ui-sref`).

The problem is that after navigating to this `tabs.settings.sub` state, my `tabs.settings.index` state is inaccessible from now on: clicking the `settings` tab always uses the `tabs.settings.sub` state.

I can think of two approaches to get back to the parent view (ie. `tabs.settings.index` state), but I don't know how to implement them, and as a consequence don't whether it's feasible:

1. Have a back button to get back to the calling view (`tabs.home` state); or
2. When clicking on the settings tab, bring to the parent view if it were to show the sub one

How can I get back to my `tabs.settings.index` state? Thanks,

Comment: your problem is little unclear..You can directly access the tabs from the tab menu.why do u need to show the back button?

Comment: @Mohit Open the link [provided](http://codepen.io/piwinux/pen/BNYXKd), and click on the `settings/sub` button ( in the `home` tab); this brings you to a *child*-view of `settings` (state name is `tabs.settings.sub`). Now how do I get to the *parent* view (`tabs.settings`)?

Comment: you can't navigate to an abstract state

Comment: @novalain sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't want to navigate to an abstract state (I just nioticed my previous comment was erroneous). My question was indeed unclear... I rewrote it with regards to the states involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this problem by showing the view of state `tabs.settings.sub` in a modal. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31245399/948128).